# Powershell issue with remote users

Tags: powershell, authentication

I am looking to create a HTML page that contains a list of Blade workstations that are either in use or free. So far via the web I have managed to find the following script but I am having an issue when trying to show the "Current Logged on User = None

The issue I am seeing is that the **$user -eq $null** will always place a *"Current Logged On User: No one is currently logged on"*

see example

```html
PC47295
DE-PROD\simwa
Current Logged On User: No one is currently logged on
Status: Online​
```

```html
$computers = Get-Content -Path c:\myscripts\computers.txt;
$Log = "C:\myscripts\usertest.txt"

$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

Get-date | Out-File $Log

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    if (!($CompName = @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class win32_ComputerSystem)[0].Name | Out-File $Log -Append))
         
        {
        #This gets the currently logged on user
        $user = @(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName | Out-File $Log -Append

        #This loop is checking if anyone is logged on
        if ($user -eq $null)
            {
                #This is returned if no one is logged on
                "Current Logged On User: No one is currently logged on" | Out-File $Log -Append
            }
        else
             {
                #This is returned if a user is logged on
                "Current Logged On User: " + $user | Out-File $Log -Append
             }
        "Status: Online" | Out-File $Log -Append
        $nl | Out-File $Log -Append
       } 
}

​
```

Comment: What's the question...?

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to get $User -eq $Null working correctly

You can see that it places a currently no one logged in when the line above say DE-Prod/simwa as the logged on user

Hope that makes sense